# Visual Studio Iteration

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017

program runs if i eliminate lines 14  through 16 
something with the "print" commmand that i do not understand.
I have never used it before and think that it maybe a way to display i 
in a label type command. This is my 4th time trying to write a VB program 
and all others do not use " Print", but display in labels.

Thanks for any help .
This assignment was given to me from Computer Science Class Instructor.

```
DIM i AS INTEGER
DIM HowMuch AS INTEGER
HowMuch = 0
FOR i = 1 TO 10
IF i < 5 THEN
HowMuch = HowMuch + 1
ELSEIF i = 5 THEN
HowMuch = HowMuch - 5
ELSE
HowMuch = HowMuch + 3
END IF
PRINT i, HowMuch
NEXT i
PRINT HowMuch
```

2 errors : line 14 and line 16 needs  parentheses

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, PRINT is a procedure for writing things to a file. Its syntax is:

```
PRINT (int FileNumber, params object[] Output)
```

If you just want to output to standard output you can use the Console class:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", i, HowMuch)
Console.WriteLine(HowMuch)
```